# Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown for multi select in my angular 6 project.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
        [placeholder]="'LP URL'"
        [data]="getLp_url"
        [settings]="lp_url_dropdownSettings"
        name="lp_url[{{i}}][{{k}}]"
        >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: Please share the solution if you have found.

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) the is no such property name. You have to remove it.